# Update ListView everytime the Data changes

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm building a Chat using PHP and Java, I'm getting the data from the chat using a Json file, and I am inserting the Data calling a PHP file that inserts a new message into my Database.

I'm listing all the messages in a `Listview`, and I am trying to update the `listview` everytime a new message is sent, my code is working, but I would like to automatically update the `Listview` when I send a new message.

I have to click at the chat room again to see the `Listview` updated. I would like to update the `listview` from both users, the receiver and the sender.

I tried to update my adapter using: `notifyDataSetChanged();` but it didn't work.

How can i do that?

Code:

**My adapter:**

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);


    // Dismiss the progress dialog
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */


    adapter =  new costumeadapter(
                    ChatRoomActivity.this,
                    contactList,
                    R.layout.chat_row,
                    new String[]{ TAG_MESSAGE, TAG_CONVERSATION },
                    new int[]{ R.id.name, R.id.conversationid });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

**Class**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

      View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);


      TextView text = (TextView) v.getTag();

      if(text == null){
         text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
          v.setTag(text);
      } 

     String pos = (String) ((Map)getItem(position)).get(TAG_POSITION);

     text.setBackgroundResource(pos.equals("left") ? R.drawable.bubble_green : R.drawable.bubble_yellow);

     conversationid = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.conversationid);

     send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {

            String getmessage = txtmessage.getText().toString();
            String getconversationid = conversationid.getText().toString();

            SendMessage mTask = new SendMessage();
            mTask.execute(sessionid,getmessage,getconversationid);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         }
     });

      return v;  

   }
```

Thanks.

Comment: first update the underlying message object used to show the chat and then call notifydatasetchanged

Comment: Can you give me a little example please?

Comment: Would you be open to using a PullToRefreshListview? Add some bling to that list mang https://github.com/erikwt/PullToRefresh-ListView

Comment: But I'm trying to build a Chat, i want to refresh automatically the listview, I dont want my users to push the screen to see a new message... But  thanks btw.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely have to use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`. So you just have to create a `listener` and make the `Listview` implements it. Into this `listener` you put `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`. Then you just call this method when each device receives the information

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **CursorLoader**, It wraps **ContentObserver**, which subscribes to changes in **ContentProvider** by specific URI.

### So...

your chat app should contain ContentProvider to work with DB, CursorLoader that loads your chat history and updates UI on db data changed...