# Listview update automatically

Tags: android, listview

I am new in Android Development. I am fetching my database from the Xampp server and display data on listview it's working fine but when I update my database I need to refresh my activity every time. I want that I should not have to refresh it, again and again, it should automatically update the data in listview as a kind of real-time something! How can I achieve this? Please, someone, help me out... Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, you need to know about WebSocket to do this type of work. Here is the tutorial will help to understand: https://www.varvet.com/blog/using-websockets-in-native-ios-and-android-apps/

Comment: You also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29950092/update-listview-everytime-the-data-changes?rq=1

Comment: You can use socket as @FaysalAhmed said. Refer the link he has provided

Comment: Thankyou! @FaysalAhmed I really found something cool in Websockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `notifyDataSetChanged()` with the adapter instance that you have created for the List view.

This will notify any change in the data model fetched from the database.

Create a Service to listen to the port continously as per your need whenever there is a change in the data, you can send a signal to the application to fetch data again and then `notifyDataSetChanged()` will update the changes.

work of your refresh functionlity will be done by Service(not Activity).

Comment: Service runs in background you can have it check whether any(according to your implementation) changes have been made. Once the flag is set(checked by service) fetch the data again that will be updated by the notifyDataSetChanged() to the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Use push Notification concept

[Android Push Notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging FCM & PHP](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

when the server update send push notification from server and receive application by using services .

Inside activity make method to refresh listview  call this method in the service.

Answer (score 0):

I think Web socket and push notification both are a Right way to solve your problem. But as per my opinion, you should go with push notification it would be good because Socket is more costly to do it for that you need to make server strong. When traffic increased in the server then the number of socket connection would be increased and you need to manage that much of socket connections. FCM/GCM push notification is easy for that. You just need to send silent push whenever update data regarding particular user only.

For this best suit Firebase database if it is suitable for you in your current state.